# What does std::match_results::size return?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm a bit confused about the following C++11 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string haystack("abcdefabcghiabc");
    std::regex needle("abc");
    std::smatch matches;
    std::regex_search(haystack, matches, needle);
    std::cout << matches.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I'd expect it to print out `3` but instead I get `1`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You only get 1 match per search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Some people have downvoted this answer. That may be for a variety of reasons, but if it is because it does not apply to the answer I criticized (no one left a comment to explain the decision), they should take note that W. Stribizew changed the code two months **after** I wrote this, and I was unaware of it until today, 2021-01-18. The rest of the answer is unchanged from when I first wrote it.

@stribizhev's solution has quadratic worst case complexity for sane regular expressions. For insane ones (e.g. "y*"), it doesn't terminate. In some applications, these issues could be [DoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) waiting to happen. Here's a fixed version:

```
string str("abcdefabcghiabc");
int i = 0;
regex rgx1("abc");
smatch smtch;
auto beg = str.cbegin();
while (regex_search(beg, str.cend(), smtch, rgx1)) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << smtch[0] << std::endl;
    i += 1;
    if ( smtch.length(0) > 0 )
        std::advance(beg, smtch.length(0));
    else if ( beg != str.cend() )
        ++beg;
    else
        break;
}
```

According to my personal preference, this will find n+1 matches of an empty regex in a string of length n. You might also just exit the loop after an empty match.

If you want to compare the performance for a string with millions of matches, add the following lines after the definition of `str` (and don't forget to turn on optimizations), once for each version:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
    str = str + str;
```

Answer (score 11):

You get `1` because [`regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) returns only 1 match, and `size()` will return the number of capture groups + the whole match value.

Your  `matches` is...:

> Object of a [match_results](http://www.cplusplus.com/match_results) type (such as cmatch or smatch) that is filled by this function with information about the match results and any submatches found.
>
> If [the regex search is] successful, it is not empty and contains a series of sub_match objects: the first [sub_match](http://www.cplusplus.com/sub_match) element corresponds to the entire match, and, if the regex expression contained sub-expressions to be matched (i.e., parentheses-delimited groups), their corresponding sub-matches are stored as successive sub_match elements in the match_results object.

Here is a code that will find multiple matches:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string str("abcdefabcghiabc");
  int i = 0;
  regex rgx1("abc");
  smatch smtch;
  while (regex_search(str, smtch, rgx1)) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << smtch[0] << std::endl;
        i += 1;
        str = smtch.suffix().str();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/GVPhl9) returning `abc` 3 times.

As this method destroys the input string, here is another alternative based on the `std::sregex_iterator` (`std::wsregex_iterator` should be used when your subject is an `std::wstring` object):

```
int main() {
    std::regex r("ab(c)");
    std::string s = "abcdefabcghiabc";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << "Match value: " << m.str() << " at Position " << m.position() << '\n';
        std::cout << "    Capture: " << m[1].str() << " at Position " << m.position(1) << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/rrkfqT), returning

```
Match value: abc at Position 0
    Capture: c at Position 2
Match value: abc at Position 6
    Capture: c at Position 8
Match value: abc at Position 12
    Capture: c at Position 14
```

Comment: Note: the above example will clobber `str` so make a copy if you need to keep it.  The important bit is obtaining `smatch.suffix().str()` which returns the text *after* the match.  The `while` loop repeats the match on the remaining string until no more matches are found.

Comment: Yes, true, in order to keep `str`, just use its copy.

Comment: @Morpheu5, if anything is still not clear, please let me know.

Comment: I have updated the answer with another `std::sregex_iterator`-based method of getting all (sub)matches with their positions inside the input string.

Answer (score 4):

What you're missing is that `matches` is populated with one entry for each capture group (including the entire matched substring as the 0th capture).

If you write

```
std::regex needle("a(b)c");
```

then you'll get `matches.size()==2`, with `matches[0]=="abc"`, and `matches[1]=="b"`.