# C++ regular expression over a stream

Tags: regex, c++11, iterator

I have a very large text file (up to a few hundred MB) that I would like to process with STL regular expression. The matching region I am looking for spans several lines and happens at least a few thousand times in the file.

Can I use stream iterators for that purpose? I've tried `std::istream_iterator<char>`, but no luck. Could one post a minimal working example?

Note, that I am looking for a solution involving only STL. In the perfect solution I would like to iterate over all matches.

**EDIT**

Once I've read the comment, I understand this is not possible. So maybe there is another way to iterate over regex matches to be found in a large text file:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string s = R"(Quick brown fox
jumps over
several lines)"; // At least 200MB of multiline text here

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

    std::regex find_jumping_fox("(Quick(?:.|\\n)+?jump\\S*?)");
    auto it = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(),        find_jumping_fox);

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = it; i != std::sregex_iterator(); ++i) {
        std::smatch match = *i;                                                 
        std::string match_str = match.str(); 
        std::cout << match_str << '\n';
    }  
}
```

Comment: “Can I use stream iterators” — simple answer: no. Bidirectional iterators are required for regular expression matching. This isn’t an arbitrary limitation, either. Your best bet is to find a class that adapts the stream iterators to a bidirectional iterator via internal caching. However, the standard library doesn’t offer this. Even `istreambuf_iterator` is only an input iterator.

Comment: It would help if you posted sample code, even if it didn't actually work. I mean, just a `main` function with a few lines, for example trying to use `std::istream_iterator`. That would help ensure others understand your question correctly.

Comment: Why we need iterate over input?? Match result of `std::regex_match` is already a sequence.

Comment: @9dan: I'm looking at the available constructors for std::basic_regex and see for instance one that needs the data given as a string. But I don't won't to load my 200MB into a string and i'm looking for another solution.

Comment: I think 0.2GB string is not that great size in these days. Real issues will arise if it can't fit in the address space (over 2GB?).

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32765645/3832970), it shows how to get multiple matches from a string.

Comment: 9dan: would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it? I did as you suggested and so far I have no problems with efficiency.

Comment: If you know that match length will be limited by some constant number M, you may consider reading your file 'page by page'. every 'page' should have a size of N+M where N is portion of big file data you load each time, and only matches starting in [0..N) position interval of a given page should be accepted

Comment: what are you gonna do with the results of your search? I'd recommend you use only grep for parsing the file and get the results and that's it but I'd like to know how you will use the result of the search

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does std::match\_results::size return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765512/what-does-stdmatch-resultssize-return)

Comment: @9dan: 200MB is a lot of data to load into memory if you don't actually have to. I really wish programs would stop doing this just because "people have lots of RAM"!

Answer (score 1):

You can't match on a stream, cause what would a failed match mean? Has the start of the regex matched and more characters need to be streamed in, or has no part of the stream matched.

But after your edit, we can find offsets and ranges of matches on a string. You'll want to use:

```
const vector<smatch> foo = { sregex_iterator(cbegin(s), cend(s), find_jumping_fox), sregex_iterator() }
```

It's explained in complete detail here: https://topanswers.xyz/cplusplus?q=729#a845