# Search (big) file via regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, search, split

I am searching a lot of files for a number of strings and some files are too big to put in memory. I tried loading chunks of 10kB or so and it worked, but what if the string I am looking for has been split - half of it in this chunk, the other half in the other? My pattern would never match. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: load one more chunk each time, so that you search in chunk N and N+1, then N+1 and N+2 ː)

Comment: The question is tagged C++, but perhaps you can use a command line tool like grep?

Comment: @Geoffroy So simple and effective - thanks! If you can, please write your comment as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: This is not a solution. It fails, if your match straddles two pages.

Comment: @robor78 I want to include parameters that grep doesn't seem to support - like only files of X size and search bytes. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: @IInspectable could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you load chunks *N* and *N + 1*, but your match stretches across chunks *N*, *N + 1*, and *N + 2*, you won't find it. You just made your code break less likely. It's still broken, though.

Comment: @DoDo He's saying that if your regex matches 20kB or more, then it will fail because you've only loaded 2 pages of candidate match data

Comment: Use a finite state machine. Or like suggested, grep, and feed it only the files that match your criteria.

Comment: @DoDo Use find to filter on file size and then pipe to grep, e.g. "find . -type f -size +4096k | grep "regex"

Comment: @robor78 so I just wasted a day of my life coding a full file crawler with symlink navigation and content searching?

Comment: @IInspectable I just make sure I load chunks >= than the size of the regex pattern?

Comment: Only possible if you can determine an upper bound for all matches ahead of time. This is not in general the case. If there is a `*` in your regular expression, the match can be an arbitrary length.

Comment: You'd need to show the regex pattern, and a sample of what you expect to match. A lot of times, markers in the text can control buffering, but you have to show something. For example, reading a line at a time, your looking for the start of something, start buffering until you find either the end or the start of that something again, then match or not, clear buffer, repeat.

Comment: It's not just that the chunk has to be greater than the size of the search pattern, but the chunks cannot be disjoint. They have to overlap by at least the size of the pattern. As @IInspectable said, if the pattern contains `*` or `+`, you're out of luck on that front, though.

Comment: Regex size and quantifiers have nothing to do with it, you are initially looking for pseudo anchors as a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

If programming the solution in C++ is not a hard constraint, try find and grep

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -size +4096k -exec grep "whale" {} +
```

- **type** f only search files
- **name** only files ending with extension txt
- **size** only files greater than 4096kb
- replace "whale" with the desired regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just run your regex on chunks. You don't say which library you're using, but you want a library that you can stream the data to. The standard C++11 regex library apparently requires a bidirectional iterator as mentioned on [C++ regular expression over a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284225/c-regular-expression-over-a-stream)

However [`libsregex`](https://github.com/openresty/sregex) claims to offer a non-backtracking implementation, and has an API that you can call with each chunk, keeping the state from the previous chunk, allowing matches that span many chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Not portable, but load your file as a memory-mapped file. The *target sequence* for C++ regex'es can be an iterator pair, so you don't need to copy that file to a `std::string`. You therefore don't need to load the whole file in RAM at once.

Of course, if you have a really bad input, the backtracking might be horrible, but that is pretty much unavoidable. If your pattern is `ab*c` and you have 4GB worth of `b` followed by a `d`, then yes you'll have to backtrack all the way back to that first `a`. And your regex implementation might not be smart enough to notice that `b*` doesn't contain `a`.