# Regex - get multiple captures at multiple lines and their positions

Tags: c++, regex

I've been trying to do this for several days but still I don't get the right result.

I need to get all captures from a whole string (including newlines) but don't return after first match. I have this regex: `(\d+)\s*;`. The result should be only numbers (not the spaces and semicolon after) and it should take them from the whole input string (which is multiline).

So, for example, from this input:

```
5;
6 ;
 7;
 8 ;
```

It should return "5", "6", "7" and "8".

Anyone know how to do that in c++?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

From links mentioned in comments, I came up with this code:

```
std::regex regex(regex_str, std::regex_constants::icase);

for (std::sregex_iterator it = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), regex); it != std::sregex_iterator(); ++it)
{
    std::smatch m = *it;

    std::cout << "\t" << m[1].str() << std::endl;
}
```

It works just fine but there is one thing I forgot to mention: I also need to get the position of every capture. Using `m.position()` I can get the position of the whole match, but if there's something before the capturing group I'm looking for, it tells me an incorrect position. So, how can I get a position of the capture?

Comment: Please show your code. I am sure you just can access the captured value with `match_object[1].str()`.

Comment: To get multiple matches, there are more than 1 way. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765512/what-does-stdmatch-resultssize-return/32765645#32765645) for an example of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex_token_iterator to achieve your goal:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string strExample = "5\n 6\n\t7 ; 8; 10";
    std::regex re("\\d+");

    for (std::sregex_token_iterator it(strExample.cbegin(), strExample.cend(), re); it != std::sregex_token_iterator(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP does not need to get all the numbers, only those that are followed with optional whitespace(s) and a semicolon. Also, why not use a raw string literal for the pattern declaration?

Comment: Why? Reread his post. For given input it shoud return all number 5, 6, 7, 8.

Comment: Yes, and if the string contains `56 books;` the `56` should not be in the results.

Comment: I don't see this info anywhere in OP post.

Comment: Re-check the OP regex :)

Comment: I guess the main problem for OP is too get all matches, not just first. My code shows how to achieve this. OP can tune it with any regex he needs.

Comment: Then it is a dupe and should be flagged.