# C++11: Safe practice with regex of two possible number of matches

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, multiple-matches

With [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/0pozIG/4), I would like to match time with or without a milliseconds (ms) field. For completeness, I write the regex here (I removed the anchors in regex101 to enable multi-line):

```
^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?:|(?:\.)([0-9]{1,6}))$
```

I kind of don't understand the C++ behavior of this. Now you see in regex101, the number of capture groups depends on the string. If there's no ms, it's 3+1 (since C++ uses match[0] for the matched pattern), and if there's ms, then it's 4+1. But then in this example:

```
std::regex timeRegex = std::regex(R"(^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?:|(?:\.)([0-9]{1,6}))$)");
std::smatch m;
std::string strT = std::string("12:00:09");
bool timeMatch = std::regex_match(strT, m, timeRegex);
std::cout<<m.size()<<std::endl;
if(timeMatch)
{
    std::cout<<m[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<m[1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<m[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<m[3]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<m[4]<<std::endl;
}
```

We see that `m.size()` is always 5, whether there is or not an ms field! `m[4]` is an empty string if there's no ms field. Is this behavior the default one in regex of C++? Or should I try/catch (or some other safety measure) when in doubt of the size? I mean... even the size is a little misleading here!

Comment: Are you asking why there are 5 groups all in all? Because you have a whole match + 4 capturing groups defined in the pattern. Whether the group matches or not, it is not important as per the ECMAScript scpes, empty groups are always pre-populated with an empty string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please check the regex101 link I provided. In case there's no ms field, it should be only 3+1, not 4+1.

Comment: I do not care, and you and all of use should not care of what regex101 shows or not, it has its own bugs. What is important, is what you have in the code. You defined 4 capturing groups - there will be 4 slots for each + 1 for the whole match at Index 0.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, so it's a bug in regex101, and the number of fields is predefined *always*?

Comment: *You* define the number of groups when writing the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there a case where the number of groups depend on the input of the user, and not on the regex itself?

Comment: It always depends on the user input, and never on the "regex itself" whatever that might mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m.size()` will always be the number of marked subexpressions in your expression plus 1 (for the whole expression).

In your code you have 4 marked subexpressions, whether these are matched or not has no effect on the size of `m`.

If you want to now if there are milliseconds, you can check:

```
m[4].matched
```

Answer (score 2):

```
m.size();// Returns the number of match results. 
         // a string is allocated for each 'Capture Group' 
         // and filled with the match substring.
```

Since smatch is a match_results

(see)
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/

size returns the number of matches it ALLOCATED which is based on the number of capture groups your regex contains.

Capture Groups:

> Parentheses group the regex between them. They capture the text matched by the regex inside them into a numbered group that can be reused with a numbered backreference. They allow you to apply regex operators to the entire grouped regex.
>
> http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

So that is why your size is going to be allocated as 5 no matter what you end up filling with regex_match(). As others have notex, the fifth being the full match.

See:
[What does std::match_results::size return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765512/what-does-stdmatch-resultssize-return)

Comment: This helps. I +1ed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`std::smatch` (a.k.a. `std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`) is basically a container that holds elements of type `std::sub_match`. The first element is the match results for your full regexp expression, and the subsequent ones hold matches for each sub-expression. Since you have 4 sub-expressions if your pattern, you are getting 5 results (4 + full match).