# Regex_match not returnning multiple values

Tags: regex, c++11

Following [What does std::match_results::size return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765512/what-does-stdmatch-resultssize-return)
I tried to get this simple string to match

```
    #include <regex>
    using namespace std;
    void main() {
    stringstream ss(
            "<tag1 abc = \"Test ABC\" def = \"Test DEF\">");                                                                 string         line;
        regex          re_open_tag("<([[:alnum:]]+)( \\w* = \\\"[\\w|\\s]*\\\")*>");
        while (getline(ss, line, '\n')) {
            for (auto i = sregex_iterator(begin(line), end(line), re_open_tag); i != sregex_iterator();
                 i++) {
                auto &match = *i;
                for (auto i = 0UL; i < match.size(); i++) printf("Match:%s\n", match[i].str().c_str());
            }
    }
}
```

It successfully matches the string as a whole but I get the following output

```
Match:<tag1 abc = "Test ABC" def = "Test DEF">
Match:tag1
Match: def = "Hello  world"
```

Where did abc=... go from the set of matches. The `std::sub_matches` number 3 which is 1 less than what I'd expect.

Comment: Are you using regex to parse XML? If you are, I'd advise you not to.

Comment: You only have two capturing groups in the pattern, you cannot expect Group 3 to appear out of nowhere.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: True, but the 2nd capture group is repeatable * times. My objective is to find how many times that 2nd capture group is repeated.