# C++ Regex infinite loop

Tags: c++, regex

I'm writing a c++ program that regex's to find the cells mentioned in a give excel range string

### e.g.

$C$5

$CC$4

$C$5:$F$89

because of the need to either match only once (i.e only one cell is being mentioned in the string) or twice (i.e. for when two cells are mentioned in the string; its a range) I have designed my program as thus:

```
    //get the cell being mentioned
    std::regex regx("\\$(\\w+)\\$(\\d+)"); 
    std::smatch match;
    //match[0] = whole match (only useful for debug) 
    //match[1] = first cell col letter ; match[2] = first cell row numb
    //match[3] = second cell col letter; match[4] = second cell row numb
    /*vectors for putting columns and rows values extracted in the while loop into*/
    std::vector<std::string> vecCol;
    std::vector<std::string> vecRow;

    //put all substring matches into a vector - This loop runs infinitely
    while (std::regex_search(inString.begin(),inString.end(), match, regx)) {
        std::cout << match[0] << "\n";
        //add them to the vecs
        vecCol.push_back(match[1].str());
        vecRow.push_back(match[2].str());
    }
```

the while loop causes an issue I don't quite understand; it gets trapped in an infinite loop  and continues to add in the same substring match (e.g. C4) each time round infinitely. this happens even if there is only one cell mentioned in the string that is passed in

Please can anyone explain what I'm getting wrong with this C++ regex?

Comment: It seems like you are `regex_search`'ing the same text continuously

Comment: Did you read the chapter Notes on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search?

Comment: A good pointer @WernerHenze, however I find that: "In order to examine all matches within the target sequence, std::regex_search may be called in a loop, restarting each time from m[0].second of the previous call. std::regex_iterator offers an easy interface to this iteration." is confusing; is this saying that each time std::regex_search is iterated through that it will go on to m[0].second without me setting up the actual syntax of the above to be "match[0].second in the loop? because if so then that wouldn't explain the infinite loop problem still - as there would be no match[0].second

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please explain? I don't understand why this question is marked a duplicate. In fact one solution for the duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780260/1023911 which shows exactly the loop that the questioner here uses (and has problems with).

Comment: @Georgec Sorry, my link was not very useful. I misunderstood the notes. I was now playing with a small example taken from cppreference. `while (regex_search(log, sm, r))` works, but `while (regex_search(log.begin(), log.end(), sm, r))` fails to compile and `while (regex_search(log.cbegin(), log.cend(), sm, r))` does not terminate (as you said). Surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, you do not change the `inString`, nor are you using an iterator that would move the regex index, so you constantly get one and the same match, and there is no `break` condition inside the loop.

Use

```
while (std::regex_search(inString, match, regx)) {
        std::cout << match[0] << "\n";
        vecCol.push_back(match[1].str());
        vecRow.push_back(match[2].str());
        inString = match.suffix().str();
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/jL2rdb). Output: `$C$5` and `$F$89`.

Note it will change `inString`. If you do not want it, use the `sregex_iterator`:

```
for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(inString.begin(), inString.end(), regx);
                         i != std::sregex_iterator();
                         ++i)
{
    std::smatch match = *i;
    std::cout << "Whole match: " << match.str() << ", Group 1: " << match.str(1) << ", and Group 2: " << match.str(2) << '\n';
    //add them to the vecs
    vecCol.push_back(match.str(1));
    vecRow.push_back(match.str(2));
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/TY7SnK), output:

```
Whole match: $C$5, Group 1: C, and Group 2: 5
Whole match: $F$89, Group 1: F, and Group 2: 89
```